Is it possible to expose all module outputs as root outputs in a workspace?
Let's say I have a Terraform module which has two outputs:

iam_role_arn
iam_role_name

And let's say that I have a workspace named workspace-a that uses this module like so:
workspace-a/main.tf
module iam {
  source = "./modules/iam"
}

In another workspace, workspace-b, I need to get the outputs from workspace-a, so I declare a terraform_remote_state data provider to access it:
workspace-b/main.tf:
data terraform_remote_state workspace_b {
  # omitted for brevity
}

In this case (workspace-a uses a module iam, workspace-b uses the remote state of workspace-a), unless I manually copy the outputs of the iam module, I can't get access to module.iam's outputs, so I would need to do this:
workspace-a/outputs.tf
output iam_role_arn {
  value = module.iam.iam_role_arn
}

output iam_role_name {
  value = module.iam.iam_role_name
}

If I only have two outputs to pass, this isn't too much work, but as I add more outputs to my module and need to expose them, the work quickly becomes daunting as I need to declare the outputs inside of the module and declare them again in workspace-a.
As an example, in my module, naftulikay/titan-network/aws, I have nearly a hundred outputs, and if I wanted the calling workspace to expose them, I'd need to write output blocks nearly a hundred times.
Is there a way to have a Terraform workspace automatically expose all of the outputs of a module so that I don't have to expose them individually in the calling workspace?

Having such dependencies between workspaces seems weird (at least to me). I'd recommend you to read When not to use multiple workspaces and Use environment directories
